# Chart.js time object labels not updating correctly

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am using *Chart.js* to draw a line graph which is based on dates. When it first loads it shows data for the current month.

```
 var dayByDayChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: <?php echo json_encode($arr_dates); ?>,
            //labels: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31],
            datasets: [{
                label: '<?php echo $thisYear; ?>',
                data: [<?php echo $rev2017; ?>],
                backgroundColor: "rgba(153,255,51,0.6)"
            }, {
                label: '<?php echo $lastYear;?>',
                data: [<?php echo $rev2016; ?>],
                backgroundColor: "rgba(255,153,0,0.6)"
            }]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    type: 'time',
                    time: {
                        displayFormats: {
                            'millisecond': 'MMM DD',
                            'second': 'MMM DD',
                            'minute': 'MMM DD',
                            'hour': 'MMM DD',
                            'day': 'MMM DD',
                            'week': 'MMM DD',
                            'month': 'MMM DD',
                            'quarter': 'MMM DD',
                            'year': 'MMM DD'
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }
        }

    });
```

You can then update the chart by selecting a date range, where I build a new set of data and pass it through using the objects and running update().

```
        dayByDayChart.data.datasets[0].data = json.this_year;
        dayByDayChart.data.datasets[1].data = json.last_year;
        dayByDayChart.data.labels = json.dates;
```

The only issue is, *Chart.js* updates the time period correctly but still has the same number of x-axis points for the dates. Which means they get duplicated over and over. Here's an example of the intial chart:

[image]

and then the Ajax updated one:

[image]

As you can see, the date range is meant to be 1st to the 9th but it spreads those dates over the previous 28 days that are in Feb.

How can I get it to update correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the docs and a couple forums I have found a solution that works. Chartsjs with the time config will try and guess the right time unit and when updating the chart dynamically it looks like it keeps the previous "guess".

Passing through the actual time unit I wanted i.e by day now allows the chart to update just once per day rather than trying to push single days over multiple ticks. here's the config example.

```
options: {
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    type: 'time',
                    time: {
                        unit: 'day',
                        displayFormats: {
                            //'millisecond': 'MMM DD',
                            'second': 'MMM DD',
                           'minute': 'MMM DD',
                            'hour': 'MMM DD',
                            'day': 'MMM DD',
                            'week': 'MMM DD',
                            'month': 'MMM DD',
                            'quarter': 'MMM DD',
                            'year': 'MMM DD'
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
```

The difference is the unit option under time.